# Can object of Parceable be safely used in Serilizable class?

Tags: android

I have class structure like:

```
Class A implements Serilizable{

    B obj = new B();
    ...
    ...
}
```

and B :

```
Class B implements Parceable {

...
}
```

I am getting following error:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcelable encountered IOException writing serializable object (name = createrequestpackage.models.QuestionsType)

Is this because I am using a Parceable object in Serilizable class and then serilizing A to send in bundle?

Comment: try implements Serializable in Class B also.

Comment: Are you sure? there are lot of B type classes in my project. I will do that if we are sure this is the reason

Comment: Is there any reasons for serializing class A? If the purpose is to pass objects in bundle, Parceable is recommended.

Comment: Just because there was no IPC. Anyways, i tried Serilizable in B still same error...

Comment: Is your questiontype serializable?

Comment: yea, it turns out there was a class that was still parceable. So either all Serilizable or all Parceable. I thought Parceable derived from serilizable .. will read more about it